# Can i access a concrete method of an abstract class in direct child class?

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, abstraction

Is there a way we can access the concrete method's of an abstract class in the direct child class as below

```
  abstract class ParameterBase
  {           
        public void test()
        { 
            string name = "testname";
            console.writeline(name);
        }          
  }

  public  class Parameter1 : ParameterBase 
  {
       //I Need to call(access) the Test() Method here i.e print "testname" in the  console         
  }
```

Now i know that we can create a instance of the child class with type as **ParameterBase** and access the **test()** method that is there in **ParameterBase()**  as below

```
   ParameterBase PB = new Parameter1();
   PB.test();
```

Comment: You can access all methods of base class which are not `private`. Remember - child class **IS A** base class.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky : Thanks,but how can i call it.Can u give an example

Comment: You can call it with `test()`. C# will try to resolve this name, can't find it in the Parameter1 class, then tries to find it in the base classes and it can be found in the ParameterBase class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to maintain the accessibility level while inheriting a class. You can do this :

```
abstract class ParameterBase
{
    public void test()
    {
        string name = "testname";
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

class Parameter1 : ParameterBase
{
    void getvalue()
    {
        Parameter1 pb = new Parameter1();
        pb.test();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this:-

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test2 t = new Test2();
        t.display();
        t.absDsisplay();
    }
}

abstract class Test1
{
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("display");
    }
    public abstract void absDsisplay();

}
class Test2 : Test1
{

    void GetValu()
    {


    }

    public override void absDsisplay()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("absDisplay");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parameter1 parameter1 = new Parameter1();
        parameter1.te();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public abstract class ParameterBase
{
    public void test()
    {
        string name = "testname";
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public class Parameter1 : ParameterBase
{
    public void te()
    {
        test();
    }
    //I Need to call(access) the Test() Method here i.e print "testname" in the  console         
}
```